# I could not get text field value in dynamic table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

So I created this number of sections based on user input.
For example I inputed 2 sections, I filled with 1 - 8 numbers, and it work just fine:

[image]

But when I inputed 4 sections and I filled with 1 - 16 numbers, but look at the section 1, the value changed I do not know why. Here's the pict:

[image]

Here my function code:

```
func getAllValue() {
    for sectionIndex in 0...finalSectionNumber - 1 {
        print("section index: \(sectionIndex)")
        print("final txt field: \(finalSectionNumber)")
        for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex) - 1 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
            let cells = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CellOutlet
            print("row index: \(rowIndex)")
            print(cells?.txtFieldSpecNumb.text ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

What did I miss here?
Can anyone help?

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are reused, when you scroll and if visibility of cell goes out of screen area, then they are reused.

You must have to take temporary array to save values and make them in sync with cell indexes. Set those values in cellForRowAt Index path method from array you created.

Comment: do u have any hint how to take the value to temporary array? do I need to create struct? because 1 section will have 4 data (4 rows)

Answer (score 3):

Remember, *cells are reused*. A cell can jump from being in one row to being another row. But even more important: This approach is completely wrong:

```
        let cells = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CellOutlet
        print("row index: \(rowIndex)")
        print(cells?.txtFieldSpecNumb.text ?? 0)
```

Never never never (did I mention "never"?) treat *view* as *model*. The cells, the text field, are *not the data*. If you want to know what the data is, *look in the data*. Consult the data model, not the table view. (Of course you have been keeping everything the user types in the text fields in your data model, haven't you?)

Comment: Hey man thanks for ur feedback here. I fairly new here, this is about MVC stuff right?
I shouldn't get the data in the View Controller, is that what you were saying?
The input in the text field of label 1,2,3,4 will be used later as my data. So I have to get the data from the view right?
any references I can read will be very helpful, thanks a lot buddy